# Initialize List<T> with index--is this a bug?

Tags: c#, list, initializer, index-error, outofrangeexception

In C# you can initialize `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` like this:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>()
{
  [0] = "Hello",
  [1] = "World"
};
```

You can also initialize `List<T>` like this:

```
var listA = new List<string>()
{
  "Hello",
  "World"
};
```

The two examples listed above compile and run with no exceptions.

However, the following example compiles, but throws an exception:

```
var listB = new List<string>()
{
  [0] = "Hello",
  [1] = "World"
};
// System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range.
// Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
// (Parameter 'index') at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.set_Item(Int32 index, T value)
```

Is this an unfinished feature, since it compiles but throws an exception? If not, shouldn't this be a compilation error?

I'm using C# 12 and ASP.NET 8

Comment: `[0]` isn't an index when you use a Dictionary

Comment: If you had `[0] = "Hello", [1] = "World", [1001] = "Test"`, what would you expect the other 1000 elements to be? Their default values? It seems unlikely most people would want this, so what would be the benefit of being able to specify indexes rather than just specifying the items?

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama I never said it should work per se. I actually agree with you. My question is why is it even allowed to compile.

Comment: It works with `new List<string>(existingList) { [0] = "a" }` where `existingList` has >= 1 item. [Example](https://rextester.com/BYT36105), so maybe that's why it has this ability.

Answer (score 6):

```
var listB = new List<string>()
{
  [0] = "Hello",
  [1] = "World"
};
```

[is compiled to](https://sharplab.io/#v2:D4AQDABCCMAsDcBYAUCAzFATBAwhA3ihMVBiLBALIAUAlAUSUwG4CGAThADYCWAzgBcAQhAC8EAHYBTAO4QAMvwEAeGGAB8dFIWTEA2mAC6YiACIAElK5cA9qYA0jPdGPjTAdRvsuAE1MoAXyRdEgDAoA===):

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
list[0] = "Hello";
list[1] = "World";
```

[From the Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers#collection-initializers):

> The preceding sample generates code that calls the [Item[TKey]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.item?view=net-8.0#system-collections-generic-dictionary-2-item(-0)) to set the values.

Of course, the exception makes sense because when you initialize the list, it has zero elements. Elements at index 0 and 1 don't exist.

Comment: Put another way: a `List<T>` is **not a `Dictionary<int, T>`**. They are different things, since a dictionary would allow you to use non-sequential indexes and a list has implied iteration order. And for this question, the list also does not let you set the index with the initializer.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I never said it should work per se. I actually agree with you. My question is why is it even allowed to compile.

Answer (score 6):

To complete [gunr2171's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78137820/284240), the first example with the dictionary does not use the indexer as in the 2nd example with the list(which tries to assign strings to list-indexes which don't exist because the list is empty). But this ...

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>()
{
  [0] = "Hello",
  [1] = "World"
};
```

... is the same as(which adds 2 new entries because it's using [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.item?view=net-8.0) property):

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();
dictionary[0] = "Hello"; // adds a new dictionary entry with the key 0 and the value "Hello"
dictionary[1] = "World"; // adds a new dictionary entry with the key 1 and the value "World"
```

Comment: _and_ lest we not forget that by using `[x] =y` in a dictionary it doesn't use `Dictionary.Add()`, that means that accidently repeating the same key can lead to an unexpected overwrite. https://dotnetfiddle.net/q1ovgH

Comment: @gunr2171 I never said it should work per se. I actually agree with you. My question is why is it even allowed to compile.

Comment: @user3163495: no idea, i also only knew the dictionary initializer syntax that comma separates the key and the value. But the assignment operator is explicitly supported, as you can see here in the second example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-initialize-a-dictionary-with-a-collection-initializer